# Check for collisions between SKSprite nodes that don't have physics bodies

Tags: swift3, collision-detection, skspritenode

I have two SkSprite nodes.

```
var player = SKSpriteNode()
var colorWheel = SKSpriteNode()
```

Is there a simple way for me to detect collisions between them without having to give them physics bodies. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of doing this using the update() method

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if player.frame.intersects(colorWheel.frame) {
        //Nodes are colliding
    }
}
```

This is just a starting point and will be triggered for each frame where the nodes are colliding. You will have to write down additional logic to handle one-off collisions etc.

Comment: does this make everything have a square hit box

Comment: both of my nodes are circles can I make them have a circular "hitbox"

Comment: That is the convenience provided by the physics environment. You should be using physicsBodies to detect collisions as they will lead to a more readable code as well. Also, physicsBodies can be made of any shape as well.